# Concatenating audio and video files without encoding using ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have 2 files:
video.webm - contains ONLY video
audio.webm - contains ONLY audio

I try to merge them into one without encoding with python-ffmpeg

```
video = ffmpeg.input('video.webm').video
audio = ffmpeg.input('audio.webm').audio
concatenated = ffmpeg.concat(video, audio, v=0, a=1)
concatenated.output('output.webm', vcodec='copy", acodec='copy').run()
```

but on output call I get

```
Stream specifier ':v' in filtergraph description [0:v][1:a]concat=a=1:n=2:v=0[s0] matches no streams.
```

What I want to do is to make it work as

```
ffmpeg -i "video.webm" -i "audio.webm" -c copy -map 0:v -map 1:a -shortest output.webm
```

does. The command gives me output file in 10 sec. I'd like to do the same, but by means of python-ffmpeg.

Comment: “Concatenate” is the wrong term here, which is probably why `ffmpeg.concat` doesn’t work—concatenate means to put them in a sequence, so the video plays and then the audio plays afterwards. Try just specifying multiple inputs, but without concatenation.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Thank you! It works

  **video = ffmpeg.input(f'{filename}-video.webm').video
  audio = ffmpeg.input(f'{filename}-audio.webm').audio
  ffmpeg.output(video, audio, f"output\{filename}.webm", vcodec="copy", acodec="copy").run()**

Comment: Great! I wasn’t sure, so I wrote it as a comment. I turned it into an answer so the next person with this problem will have an easier time finding the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Concatenate” means making one stream run after the other, but you want to merge both streams at the same time. So, remove the `ffmpeg.concat` step, and just pass both streams into one call to `ffmpeg.output`:

```
video = ffmpeg.input('video.webm').video
audio = ffmpeg.input('audio.webm').audio
ffmpeg.output(
    video,
    audio,
    'output.webm',
    vcodec='copy',
    acodec='copy',
).run()
```